# How do you use SSIS packages?

Tags: ssis

I have been learning about SSIS recently, and I can see its very usefull sometimes.

But what I don't know is how do I use the package once it does what I want, without starting the SSIS and run it from there. Am I suppose to compile it to an exe or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main ways to run this through s job on your SQL server. It depends on what version of visual studio you are running. The first way would be to try from the file menu and look for save package as... Choose it then you are saving the dtsx package off into a folder. Then go into ssms and create  new job pointing it to that dtsx file by choosing SQL server integration services package and file system source. 
The second way would involve setting up an integration services database catalog on your SQL server first. Right click on the catalog folder if you see it and select new integration services catalog. Then in visual studio you would select the project menu at the top of the screen and then deploy. You enter the database server name and a folder to deploy to. Then back in ssms you create a job pointing to the integration services catalog instead of the file system.